# Jordan measurable sets with Jordan curve boundaries

Tags: geometry, measure-theory

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded, connected, Jordan measurable set. Under what extra assumptions on $S$ (if such can be found) is the set's boundary $\partial S$ a Jordan curve?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to define the terms of your question. Are you looking for an equivalent condition to $\partial S$ being a Jordan curve? What 'language' do you want it phrased in? Do you care if $\partial S$ is only composed of finitely (or countably) many Jordan curves? Etc.